# nested model form and update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, update-attributes

I have a nested-model form with a one-to-many relationship between a class Project and class TeamMember, and in the controller, an update function like :

`@project = Project.find(params[:id])`

```
@project.update_attributes(params[:project])
```

Now, I'd like to set some fields that are not set in the form for some of the team members before the saving happens. I cannot use the update_attributes function as is to do so.

What would be the best way to do it ?

Thanks,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` function. You might have something like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team

  # also this will be useful
  validates_associated :team
end
```

In your forms you will want to use the `fields_for` method to nest your attributes. That might look something like:

```
<% form_for(@project) do |p| %>
  <%= p.error_messages %>
  <!-- Project name -->
  <%= p.text_field :name %>

  <% f.fields_for(@project.team) do |t| %>
    <!-- Team Name -->
    <%= t.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Create Project' %>
<% end %>
```

When you submit the form you will be able to call `@project.update_attributes(params[:project])` and it will work. You can also `raise params.inspect` to see how the params are nested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, in the controller, I wanted to use @project.attributes=params[:project], then modify some fields, and only then save. (so not using directly @project.update_attributes). But it didn't work with Rails 2.3.8. I finally found the reason (https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4766-nested_attributes-fails-to-updatedestroy-when-association-is-loaded-between-setting-attributes-and-saving-parent)

Comment: Nicolas, you should add this as an answer and answer your own question if this is the problem. I think this bug is also the same problem I'm having as well.